# ¿Cómo hago un contador diario mensual y anual en JS?

Tags: javascript

Veran tengo un proyecto donde pones una tareas pendientes y al hacer click te salta una modal que dice si ya los terminaste o no y si pones si se pone en una lista de tareas terminadas, si cliqueak aun no termino te salta otra modal que te da un mensaje motivacional, quiero hacer un contador que cuente as tareas terminadas al dia mes y año pero ni chat gpt me ah podido ayudar, eh tratado hacer durante dos dias y nada, el proyecto sigue en mi disco duro duro asique no puedo proporcionar link.
Aqui esta ni código para que lo revisen

```
'''
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const lista = [];
  let fechaActual = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
  let contadores = {
    diario: 0,
    mensual: 0,
    anual: 0,
  };

  const botonAgregarTarea = document.getElementById("agregarTarea");
  if (botonAgregarTarea) {
    botonAgregarTarea.addEventListener("click", agregarTarea);
  }

  const modoToggleButton = document.getElementById("modoToggle");
  if (modoToggleButton) {
    modoToggleButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModo);
  }

  function toggleModo() {
    const body = document.querySelector("body");
    body.classList.toggle("light-mode");
    body.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
  }

  function marcarComoTerminada(indice) {
    if (indice >= 0 && indice < lista.length) {
      const tarea = lista[indice];

      Swal.fire({
        title: "¿Has terminado esta tarea?",
        text: tarea,
        icon: "question",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: "Sí, marcar como terminada",
        cancelButtonText: "Aún no la termino",
      }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
          if (!tarea.includes(" - Terminado")) {
            lista[indice] += " - Terminado";

            // Incrementar los contadores según la fecha actual
            const fechaTarea = new Date().toLocaleDateString();

            if (fechaTarea === fechaActual) {
              contadores.diario++;
            }

            const mesActual = new Date().toLocaleDateString("es-ES", {
              month: "long",
            });
            if (fechaTarea.includes(mesActual)) {
              contadores.mensual++;
            }

            const añoActual = new Date().getFullYear().toString();
            if (fechaTarea.includes(añoActual)) {
              contadores.anual++;
            }

            // Actualizar la interfaz y mostrar un mensaje de éxito
            actualizarLista();
            actualizarContadores();
            Swal.fire({
              title: "¡Tarea marcada como terminada!",
              icon: "success",
              confirmButtonText: "Aceptar",
            });
          }
        } else {
          mostrarMensaje(mensajeMotivacion);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  function agregarTarea() {
    const nuevaTarea = prompt("Ingresa la nueva tarea:");
    if (nuevaTarea !== null && nuevaTarea.trim() !== "") {
      lista.push(nuevaTarea);
      actualizarLista();
    }
  }

  function actualizarLista() {
    const listaTareasDiv = document.getElementById("listaTareas");
    const listaTareasTerminadasDiv = document.getElementById(
      "listaTareasTerminadas"
    );

    listaTareasDiv.innerHTML = "";
    listaTareasTerminadasDiv.innerHTML = "";

    lista.forEach((tarea, indice) => {
      const tareaDiv = document.createElement("div");
      tareaDiv.classList.add("task-item");

      const mensajeDiv = document.createElement("div");
      mensajeDiv.classList.add("click-message");
      mensajeDiv.textContent = "Click para marcar como terminada";

      tareaDiv.textContent = tarea;
      tareaDiv.appendChild(mensajeDiv);

      if (!tarea.includes(" - Terminado")) {
        tareaDiv.addEventListener("click", () => marcarComoTerminada(indice));
        listaTareasDiv.appendChild(tareaDiv);
      } else {
        // La tarea está terminada
        tareaDiv.classList.add("task-item-terminada");
        listaTareasTerminadasDiv.appendChild(tareaDiv);
      }

      const saltoDeLinea = document.createElement("br");
      listaTareasDiv.appendChild(saltoDeLinea);
      listaTareasTerminadasDiv.appendChild(saltoDeLinea.cloneNode());
    });
  }

  function actualizarContadores() {
    // Actualizar la visualización de los contadores en la interfaz
    const contadorDiarioElement = document.getElementById("contadorDiario");
    const contadorMensualElement = document.getElementById("contadorMensual");
    const contadorAnualElement = document.getElementById("contadorAnual");

    contadorDiarioElement.textContent = contadores.diario.toString();
    contadorMensualElement.textContent = contadores.mensual.toString();
    contadorAnualElement.textContent = contadores.anual.toString();
  }

  actualizarLista();
  actualizarContadores();
});
```

'''

Comment: Cada tarea debe ser un objeto, y debe tener al menos las propiedades `nombre`, `fechaInicio` y `fechaFin`. Tu lista de tareas almacena objetos de ese tipo (no de simples string como lo estas haciendo). Luego es cosa de realizar consultas usando funciones como `find` o `filter` para obtener las tareas terminadas de un día, mes o año

Comment: gracias lo probare

Comment: el contaddor mensual falla no se porque, no me saltan errores en la consola

Comment: Estimado tu pregunta tiene el problema que no has puesto un [MCVE], no es la idea que pongas 1000 líneas de código que no se ejecutan porque además falta el HTML asociado